# SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert data into one of the 3 tables in a database using PDOs. When I call the insert function below, and get the error: `SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected.`[image]

Comment: please don't post an "image of" code, but actual code so we can see exactly what those quotes are. and show full code while you're at it for your variables. Your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I tried doing that, but unfortunately the formatting is screwed up when I do that and becomes unreadable.

Comment: when posting code there is an option to format it using the code formatting option (if lines don't appear as code try adding spaces to that line)

Comment: so, where are we with this question? I posted an answer almost a 1/2 hour prior to this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code I didn't see where or when you selected the db. see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) for more info.

But to be clear this is what I', referring to

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

as you can see the last variable is the dbname.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I fixed that, but now I get this: 

`Warning:  PDO::__construct() expects parameter 4 to be array, string given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/websys/lab9/insert.php on line 7`


`Fatal error:  Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/websys/lab9/insert.php on line 8`

The snippet starts on line 5.

Comment: you need to accept this as an answer and ask a new question. try copy pasting your code in the next question instead of adding a picture, not the complete query is shown in the picture

Comment: You do see that the questioner was using PDO. **Dont you?** So why are you suggesting using `mysqli`?

Comment: The answer doesn't support your posted code nor will it work with PDO (that's mixing MySQL APIs. You showed us PDO code as an image, but this answer shows as using mysqli_. Giving my head a serious shake here. @David.Sparky

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can't remember why I gave this answer and I don't see any edits to it either (that would suggest the question was edited). The OP marked my answer. As I count both you and riggsfolly what would you do in my position? Should I remove the answer?

Comment: @davejal Hard to say Dave. I'm not questioning "you", I'm questioning the OP himself. Far as I can tell, the question was never edited. There's no revision showing for it. I'd just leave it because it *technically* shows that a solution was found. Maybe he chose the wrong answer to accept. Oh well, what can you do ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok thanks, was just asking out of morality.

Answer (score 2):

*Probably going out on a limb here*.

It seems to me that you haven't created any of the variables/arrays for your connection, or is not configured correctly. (Not enough code posted in your question).

From the manual on PDO connection http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Example #1 Connecting to MySQL

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
?>
```

Example #2 Handling connection errors

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Plus, looking at the "image of" your code, it looks to me like you are using regular quotes around your columns, rather than ticks. Those are **two different animals** altogether.

```
INSERT INTO Students ('RIN', 'First Name', 'Last Name' ...
```

and having spaces between words, where yes; ticks must be used.

Therefore, you need to modify your code to read as

```
INSERT INTO Students (`RIN`, `First Name`, `Last Name` ...
```

and changing the quotes to ticks as outlined above for all the other column names. I wasn't going to type everything out here.

You also need to check for errors with exceptions in the DSN. Using what you have now, isn't enough.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Example #1 Create a PDO instance and set the error mode

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

- Make sure that you chose (and created) the right database/table and that you did in fact create all those columns and using the right types and lengths.

If you get errors for something that MySQL may complain about (such as apostrophes), then you will need to escape your data; something you should be doing anyway.

Consult the following, and use a prepared statement:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php